# Google hashbang ajax page indexing

Tags: seo

According to [Goolge's docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started), the almighty Google spider will look at this url:

```
www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value
```

as then instead go to this url

```
www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value
```

(where you could put a static snapshot of your ajax page)

---

My question is: can I omit the `key=value`? That is, would this work:

```
...com/ajax.html#!  ---->  ...com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_
```

or does Google require you to have something after your hashbang?

Comment: Simple redirect (in apache 301) or canonical. And look to https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ for better links, experience

Comment: I'm one of the co-founder of [a service dedicated to Ajax site crawling](http://www.seo4ajax.com), I can assure you it should work without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is mandatory after #!. 
So URL as `www.example.com/ajax.html#!` will work and Google will request `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=`

Note that there is always an equal sign after the _escaped_fragment_ parameter.